# Advice on using crontab with bash

Tags: bash, cron

I want to make a cron job that checks if a folder exists, and it if does to delete all the contents of that folder. For example, I know that the following will delete the contents of my folder in using cron:

```
0 * * * * cd home/docs/reports/;rm -r *
```

However, I realized that if the folder is removed (or the wrong file path is given) instead of the contents of that folder being deleted, `cd` fails and all files are deleted on my operating system. To prevent this from happening (again) I want to check for the existence of the folder first, and then to delete the contents. I want to do something like the following, but I'm not sure how to use a bash script with cron.

```
if [ -d "home/docs/reports/" ]; then
    cd home/docs/reports/;rm -r *
fi
```

I'm new to bash and cron (in case it is not obvious).

Comment: Not sure why you need to `cd` to the directory to do the command -- just specify the full path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `cron` uses `/bin/sh` to execute commands.  `sh` is typically a subset of `bash`, and you're not doing anything bash-specific.

Execute the `rm` command only if the `cd` command succeeds:

```
0 * * * * cd home/docs/reports/ && rm -r *
```

<strike>**NOTE** Please wait a few minutes while I test this.  If this note is gone, I've tried it and it works.</strike>

Yes, it works.  (Note that testing whether the directory exists is less reliable; it's possible that the directory exists but you can't `cd` into it, or it might cease to exist between the test and the `cd` command.)

But actually you don't need to use a compound command like that:

```
 0 * * * * rm -r home/docs/reports/*
```

Still the `&&` trick, and the corresponding `||` operator to execute a second command only if the first one *fails*, can be very useful for more complicated operations.

(Did you mean `/home/docs` rather than `home/docs`?  The latter will be interpreted relative to your home directory.)

Though this worked ok when I tried it, use it at your own risk.  Any time you combine `rm -r` with wildcards, there's a risk.  If possible, test in a directory you're sure you don't care about.  And you might consider using `rm -rf` if you want to be as sure as possible that everything is deleted.  Finally, keep in mind that the `*` wildcard doesn't match files or directories whose names start with `.`.

```
#include <stddisclaimer.h>
```

**EDIT :**

The comments have given me a better understanding of what you're trying to do.  These are files that users are going to download shortly after they're created (right?), so you don't want to delete anything less than, say, 5 minutes old.

Assuming you have GNU findutils, you can do something like this:

```
0 * * * *  find /home/docs/reports/* -cmin +5 -delete 2>/dev/null
```

Using the `-delete` option to `find` means you're deleting files and/or directories one at a time, not deleting entire subtrees; the main difference is that an old directory with a new file in it will not be deleted.  Applying `-delete` to a non-empty directory will fail with an error message.

Read the GNU find documentation (`info find`) for more information on the `-cmin` and `-delete` options.  Note that `-ctime` operates on the time of the last status change of the file, *not* its creation time (Unix doesn't record file creation times).  For your situation, it's likely to be the same.

(If you omit the `/*` on the path, it will delete the `reports` directory itself.)

Comment: Thanks @Keith - is there is a less critical operation that I could try first to check that this is ok? For example, if I did ` 0 * * * * ls /home/docs/reports/*` would that just list all the files? I did mean `/home/....` originally.

Comment: @celenius: Yes, but the listing will go to stdout, which `crond` will *try* to e-mail to you. If that fails, you can do `ls ... > some-file`. For testing crontab commands, I often use `* * * * *` (don't forget to clean up your crontab after testing). Helpful hint: I keep my crontab in a version control system.

Comment: @celenius: One thing to watch out for (as I discovered when I forgot to clean up my own crontab  after testing this): if there are no files in `/home/doc/reports`, then `rm -r /home/docs/reports/*` will generate an error message, which you'll receive as an automatic e-mail.  Consider adding `2>/dev/null` to discard any error messages.

Comment: thanks for the advice. So would the final line be: `0 * * * * rm -r home/docs/reports/* 2>/dev/null` ?

Comment: @celenius: Yes (except that you probably mean `/home/...` rather than `home/...`).  Note that if files are created there at arbitrary times, this will sometimes remove files immediately after they're created.  Is that what you want, or do you want to remove files only after you've had a chance to look at them?  Why not just avoid creating those files in the first place?

Comment: (ah, yes `/home`!). I want to delete files from a temporary folder on an hourly basis after a user generates them. They presumably download them so I never need to see what they are.

Comment: @celenius: Sure, but if a file is downloaded 2 seconds before your cron job runs, you'll delete it before the user has a chance to download it.  Consider using a script that invokes `find` to remove files more than N minutes old.

Comment: That's a good idea. So I could do something like this? `find /home/docs/reports/* -cmin +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your entire command (including the if logic) into a script.sh.

Specify #!/bin/bash at the top of your script.

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Then specify the full path of the script in your cron job.

Comment: Also a good solution. I don't think it's necessary in this case, but it's a good technique.  (Don't forget to `chmod +x` the script!)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing by far is to do SHELL=/bin/bash at the top of your crontab.  Works for me.